# T-SQL Conditional IF statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a recordset that looks like this:

DocID (Primary Key) | Version | Name

4 | 1 | FileNameA

8 | 2 | FileNameA

6 | 1 | FileNameB

3 | 1 | FileNameC

What I need to do is only show a unique file name where the version number is greater than 1.

So I need a SQL query that would return a recordset that looks like this:

DocID (Primary Key) | Version | Name

8 | 2 | FileNameA

6 | 1 | FileNameB

3 | 1 | FileNameC

All I am using now is a basic select statement from my table. I am not sure if this is possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FileNameB and FileNameC have version = 1, not greater than. Why are they in your expected results?

Comment: @vikrantislav because there is only one version of those, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your desired rows from a subselect and join on that:

```
SELECT DocID, Version, Name
FROM MyTable t
INNER JOIN (SELECT Name, MAX(Version) as Version
            FROM MyTable
            GROUP BY Name) sub
  ON Sub.name = t.name
  AND sub.version = t.version
```

Comment: Hello, I am getting:

Ambiguous column name 'Version'
Ambiguous column name 'Name'.

Comment: @user993514 - put `t.` in front of both of those.

Comment: I fixed that problem, but now I get this:
<br>
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: @user993514 there's no `.` in line 3, so can you post your actual query in to the original question?